# Phoenix select form control has no effect

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, changeset

I am trying to edit the locale_id field in table "users".
The table "locales" contains only id, code(like "en" or "ua"), name and default timestamps.

Here is my *.eex form code:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, user_path(@conn, :update, @current_user), [multipart: true], fn f -> %>
...
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Language</label>
    <%= select f, :locale_id, @locales, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
...
<% end %>
```

Controller code:

```
plug :load_locales when action in [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

...

def edit(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user = Repo.get!(Rumbl.User, id)
  changeset = Rumbl.User.changeset(user)
  render(conn, "edit.html", user: user, changeset: changeset)
end

def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "user" => user_params}) do
  user = Repo.get!(Rumbl.User, id)
  changeset = Rumbl.User.changeset(user, user_params)

  case Repo.update(changeset) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :show, user))
    {:error, changeset} ->
      render(conn, "edit.html", user: user, changeset: changeset)
  end
end

defp load_locales(conn, _) do
  locales = Repo.all from(c in Rumbl.Locale,
                          order_by: c.id,
                          select: {c.name, c.id})
  assign(conn, :locales, locales)
end
```

The schema from model "user":

```
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :username, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string
    belongs_to :locale, Rumbl.Locale
    has_many :friends, Rumbl.Friend
    has_many :devices, Rumbl.Device
    timestamps
  end
```

From model "locale":

```
  schema "locales" do
    field :name, :string
    field :code, :string
        has_many :users, Rumbl.User
    timestamps
  end
```

Comment: Have you specified the field in your changeset function?

Comment: Let us know what is happening when you submit the form? Do you see an error? Does the console show anything? Can you post the entire user model?

Comment: @Gazler Thanks, it was missing :) Added it and everything worked fine.

Comment: @ScottS. I added locale_id to
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(name username locale_id), [])
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
    |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20)
  end
and everything ran. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I added `locale_id` to

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, ~w(name username locale_id), [])
  |> unique_constraint(:username)
  |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20)
end
```

and everything ran.